# Squish: How to restart an application already under test

Tags: wpf, squish

I am using Squish for windows 6.3.1.  I connect to my WPF application remotely using an attachable AUT.  If I run the application with restarting it, it is working fine.  However, If I kill the startWinAUT and application and then restart them the defined object map gets messed up.  What I mean by this is in debug mode my objects and object types show as Custom_0, 1, 2 etc.  Normally this would have the WPF object names with WPF_Control type.  When this happens the objects defined in my map do not match up with application so I get LookupError: Object..blah blah blah..not found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mID68.jpg)

Comment: There was a bug in Squish 6.2.x which could have been related, but it has been fixed a while ago. I recommend to not kill startwinaut.exe, but instead close the application the way a user would, or via currentApplicationContext().detach(). If the problem persists, I recommend contacting the vendor, ideally with an example test suite for easy and quick reproduction of the problem at their end.

Comment: I went ahead and contacted froglogic.  I tried not kiling the aut but that did not help.  I'm guessing there is a windows component that is missing from the remote machine causing the issue.  Thanks for the input.